Optimizing of complex SUM-DISTINCT problem in SSAS Multidimensional OLAP
I have Cube with Revenue, Quantity etc. I have TimeDimension (granularity quarters), user can select set of quarters. Dimension Size of store. Select some Quarters and Sizes of stores creates playground - Universe for calculations. There are also Stores (not necessary in one Size) and ProductHierarchy Company - Brand - SKU.
Direct calculations as SUM(...) for ProductHierarchy are simple.
I need also some distincts for ProductHierarchy, Stores, it is also simple.
I need also some Universe total, I do it over dynamic named sets, in it is the basic filters for Quarters and Sizes from WHERE or subquery cube.
The problem starts with need to sum total revenues (incl.Universe, but for all SKUs) of Stores that solved some Company/Brand/SKU in the universe.
It is used for Distribution metric, that is SUM(Revenue)/SUM(TotalRevenueOfSellingStores).
If I select eg. Brand,  I need to filter from set of Stores theese ones, that solved something from current ProductHierarchy and then SUM Revenue for this Stores over this set. This cannot be handled via the M:N dimension because it creates duplicates.
Sample (simplifies without Size dimension and without Brands):



Company
SKU




CompA
SKU1


CompA
SKU2


CompB
SKU3



Sales Facts:



Quarter
SKU
Store
Revenue




2023Q1
SKU1
Store1
100


2023Q1
SKU2
Store1
200


2023Q1
SKU1
Store2
300


2023Q1
SKU3
Store1
100


2023Q2
SKU1
Store1
200


2023Q2
SKU2
Store2
100



So, total revenue for Stores was (i have it precalculated in other fact table):



Quarter
Store1
Store2




2023Q1
400
300


2023Q2
200
100


2023Q1-2
600
400



And what I need:



Quarter
Company - SKU
SellingInStore1
SellingInStore2
TotalRevenueOfSellingStore




2023Q1
CompA - SKU1
YES
YES
700


2023Q1
CompA - SKU2
YES
NO
400


2023Q1
CompA
YES
YES
700


2023Q1
CompB - SKU3
YES
NO
400


2023Q1
CompB
YES
NO
400


2023Q2
CompA - SKU1
YES
NO
200


2023Q2
CompA - SKU2
NO
YES
100


2023Q2
CompA
YES
YES
300


2023Q2
CompB - SKU3
NO
NO
0


2023Q2
CompB
NO
NO
0


2023Q1-2
CompA - SKU1
YES
YES
1000


2023Q1-2
CompA - SKU2
YES
YES
1000


2023Q1-2
CompA
YES
YES
1000


2023Q1-2
CompB - SKU3
YES
NO
600


2023Q1-2
CompB
YES
NO
600



I tried using sum over filter of Stores:
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[StoreTotalRevenue]     
 AS SUM (
             FILTER([Store].[Store].[Store].MEMBERS, ([Measures].[Quantity])<>NULL), 
             ([Measures].[StoreRevenue]) -- precalculated sum of Store Rev per Quarter and Store
        )

However it took about 1 minute for 2000 stores, 8 Q and 1.5 millions rows (incl. 3 Store Sizes). And this needs to work interactively.

A pity you are not using icCube ;-) https://www.iccube.com/
